# What is the second order derivative of the dot product $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, inner-products

Given $d>1$, $\mathbf{x}\in{\rm I\!R}^d$, and two multivariate functions $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} : {\rm I\!R}^d\rightarrow{\rm I\!R}^d$, what is the second derivative of $f : {\rm I\!R}^d\rightarrow{\rm I\!R} $
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})^T\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})
$$
with respect to $\mathbf{x}$?

The first derivative is 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x}) =  \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})^T\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x}) + \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})^T\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})
$$
which is a row vector of size $d$ when using the numerator layout.

But I do not know how to differentiate again since $\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}$ are $3$-by-$3$ matrices...

I tried to develop these equations in a simple situation where $d=2$, but I obtain a quite complicated matrix and I am looking for a clear formula, in any dimension $d>1$, where only $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ and their derivatives appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to work in index notation. Write $f=\sum_{i=1}^du_iv_i$ so$$(\nabla f)_j=\sum_i[(\partial_ju_i)v_i+u_i\partial_jv_i]=[(\nabla u)v+(\nabla v)u]_j,$$i.e. $\nabla f=(\nabla u)v+(\nabla v)u$. Now for the second derivative:$$(\nabla^2f)_{jk}=\partial_k(\nabla f)_j=\sum_i[(\partial_j\partial_ku_i)v_i+\partial_ju_i\partial_kv_i+\partial_ku_i\partial_jv_i+u_i\partial_j\partial_kv_i].$$Note this includes rank-$3$ tensors we might denote $\nabla^2u,\,\nabla^2v$, but writing in terms of those without indices requires some clarification on the notation. For example, if we take $(\nabla^2u)_{jki}:=(\partial_j\partial_ku_i)$, we get$$\nabla^2f=(\nabla^2u)\cdot v+(\nabla u)\cdot(\nabla v)+(\nabla v)\cdot(\nabla u)+(\nabla^2v)\cdot u,$$where each $\cdot$ contracts the factors' last index. This is the general Leibniz rule with non-commuting factors (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for a treatment of the commuting case, e.g. if $u,\,v$ were scalars).

Comment: Are you sure it's rank-$3$ tensors? It's just $d$-by-$d$ matrices, so rank-$2$ tensors no?
Is it easy to continue to differentiate to obtain order $3$, $4$ derivatives and so on using such index notation and higher order tensors? 
Also, I guess there is an extra $f$ in your last equation?

Comment: @TL Apologies for that typo.But yes, if we differentiate $u\cdot v$ a total of $n$ times, there must be a term in which $u$ is differentiated $n$ times, giving a rank-$n+1$ tensor.